# Task to delete users without mount points in /home (using register and when)

Tags: ansible

I have a list of users that I want to delete (del_users), but I only want to delete those that haven't mountpoint on your /home directory. My currently code is:

```
- name: Verify if exist mount point on /home
  shell: "mount -l | grep bind | grep -ci {{ item }}"
  ignore_errors: yes
  check_mode: False
  loop: "{{ del_users }}"
  register: del_users_reg

- name: Delete user if doesn't exist mount point on /home
  user:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: absent
    remove: yes
  when: item.stdout_lines == 0
  loop: del_users_reg
```

When I execute this task appears the next error:

```
TASK [osbasic : Verify if exist mount point on /home] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
 [WARNING]: Consider using the mount module rather than running 'mount'.  If you need to use command because mount is insufficient you can add 'warn: false' to this command task or set 'command_warnings=False' in ansible.cfg to get rid
of this message.

failed: [LGAUSUX10] (item=user1) => {"changed": true, "cmd": "mount -l | grep bind | grep -ci usuario1", "delta": "0:00:00.025089", "end": "2019-06-11 13:33:40.978563", "item": "user1", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-06-11 13:33:40.953474", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "0", "stdout_lines": ["0"]}

TASK [osbasic : Verify if exist mount point on /home] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
...ignoring

TASK [osbasic : Delete user if doesn't exist mount point on /home] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [osbasic : Delete user if doesn't exist mount point on /home] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [LGAUSUX10]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: del_users_reg. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."}
        to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/osbasic.retry

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
LGAUSUX10                  : ok=9    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

How could put a condition for delete users only if the result of first task is 0?

Answer (score 2):

Several problems in your playbook.

1. `loop` is basically expecting a list, not a string containing a variable name. You need to expand your variable with a jinja2 expression => `loop: "{{ some_list_variable }}"`
2. It will be hard to give you the correct syntax without seeing the exact data structure of your result var but... Typically, the register from a loop contains a `results` list of hashes, each containing info about the ran command for each loop iteration. This is your base loop for the second task => `loop: "{{ del_users_reg.results }}"`

If you still have trouble fixing your playbook, update your question with a debug of the registered var and I will update my answer accordingly.